# Call the scene when image target is scanned

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

everyone!..
 I want build a Trivia Augmented Reality Game, AR scene is working properly on cube object. I have the game scene. ...
Anyone can help me, "how to make the game scene appear when my image target is detected ?".

Comment: Are you using Vuforia or AR Media or some other SDK for your AR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *SceneManager.LoadScene* method to load a scene as follow -

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("GameSceneName");
```

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) is the documentation for *SceneManager.LoadScene* method.

Answer (score 0):

Which AR SDK you are using? Vuforia or what?
If you are using Vuforia, you can use ImageTargetBehaviou.CurrentStatus property.
When your image target is detected, currentState should be equal to

```
    imageTargetTemplate.CurrentStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED
```

Then you can use SceneManager.LoadScene method as @Mukesh Saini said.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code that I have written and tested on my own project. It works for me upon object scan. I placed this script in my Image Target, just make your own changes to the Scene names under the *//Go to Scene, IF detect a target* section. Afterwards, drag your Image Target in the Image Target component in Unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace Vuforia
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomsTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
                                                ITrackableEventHandler
    {

        public ImageTargetBehaviour imageTarget;
        private ImageTargetBehaviour[] allImageSources;


        #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

        private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

        #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES



        #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

        void Start()
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
            if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            {
                mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
            }

            imageTarget = (ImageTargetBehaviour)gameObject.AddComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>();
        }

        #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS



        #region PUBLIC_METHODS

        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
        /// tracking state changes.
        /// </summary>
        public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
            {
                OnTrackingFound();
            }
            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }

        #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS



        #region PRIVATE_METHODS


        private void OnTrackingFound()
        {
            Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

            // Enable rendering:
            foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }

            // Enable colliders:
            foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");


            //Go to Scene, IF detect a target

            if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "Scene 1")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("YourUnityProjectName 1");
            }

            if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "Scene 2")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("YourUnityProjectName 2");
            }


            if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "Scene 3")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("YourUnityProjectName 3");
            }
        }


        private void OnTrackingLost()
        {
            Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

            // Disable rendering:
            foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }

            // Disable colliders:
            foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
        }

        #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
    }
}
```